# ASP.Net MVC3 C# query regarding viewing data stored in a database

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-web-developer-2010

I have a question regarding the MVC3 C# Tutorial.

When creating Controller, it automatically creates the Views for you, and Index.cshtml is created (path being /Views/News/Index.cshtml). This code looks like the below:

```
@model IEnumerable<dale_harrison.Models.News>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            News_Entry
        </th>
        <th>
        News_Date
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Entry)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Date)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

This works fine, however, I would like to display the contents of @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Entry) and @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.News_Date) on my homepage, which is in a different View.

I tried to copy the code from Index.cshtml into a new view (path being /Views/Home/homepage.cshtml), but it fails with the error: "NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user code" - sorry, but I'm unsure what this means?

Would someone mind explaining why simply copying the code to display data from the database from one View to another View doesn't work? Apologies for being thick, but I'm a beginner with no coding background.

I can post the Controller code if required.

Many thanks.

Comment: It means you are not passing a model to your other view. when you return the home view in the controller you need to pass the same model like you will have done in the news action.

Comment: does error occured when navigation to home.aspx?

Comment: Thank you Musefan, that explains it perfectly - all working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you omitted passing model to view when calling it.you can do this like :

```
public ActionResult HomePage()
{
    IEnumerable<dale_harrison.Models.News> model = new List<dale_harrison.Models.News>();  
    // prepare your model (populate it with proper data)

    return View(model);
}
```